# simple text will not appear in a list form in sharepoint 2010

Tags: 2010

I am trying to publish a List form in Sharepoint 2010 which I have done and just trying to enter in some text as a description to a fields function. When I publish the form there is a field I would like to have radio buttons and to get that to work I have to go to "Form Options" and change the default selection from "Modify the existing Infopath Form" to "Use the default Sharepoint Form". When I do this the form displays as I would like it to but all the text that I add to the fields describing their function disappears and I am left with only the fields themselves.

I am fairly junior to Sharepoint so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I wish I could as I have already tried this but when trying to use Sharepoint designer is returns the message that editing the site with SharePoint Designer has been disabled and cannot be used. I cannot contact my administrator, it just inst possible.

Answer (score 0):

Look at editing the form in SharePoint designer instead of InfoPath.

Once you have the site open in SharePoint designer, navigate to the list and there will be a section for "Forms" with Display Edit and New forms available for editing.